# Want to Extract Both <messageid> using PHP from following XML response

Tags: php, xml, response

I have an SMS API, And getting the XML response want to extract  for all outgoing SMS using PHP, Please Guide me friends. 
This is MY API response

```
<response xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<action>sendmessage</action>
<data>
  <acceptreport>
  <statuscode>0</statuscode>
  <statusmessage>Message accepted for delivery</statusmessage>
  <messageid>223639802</messageid>
  <originator>88434</originator>
  <recipient>923336458112</recipient>
  <messagetype>SMS:TEXT</messagetype>
  <messagedata>testing by JAved for DLS</messagedata>
</acceptreport>
<acceptreport>
  <statuscode>0</statuscode>
  <statusmessage>Message accepted for delivery</statusmessage>
  <messageid>223639803</messageid>
  <originator>88434</originator>
  <recipient>923497105188</recipient>
  <messagetype>SMS:TEXT</messagetype>
  <messagedata>testing by JAved for DLS</messagedata>
</acceptreport>
</data>
</response>
```

Comment: You are expected to do some research and attempt to accomplish your task on your own before posting here.  This is not a "do this for me" service.  Once you have made your own honest attempt, if you are still stuck, feel free to update this question to include the code that you tried, the desired result, the actual result (including any error messages), and what debugging you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the comment above and at least try to solve the problem yourself next time.
This should solve your issue:

```
<?php


$xmlstr = '<response xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                <action>sendmessage</action>
                                <data>
                                <acceptreport>
                                  <statuscode>0</statuscode>
                                  <statusmessage>Message accepted for delivery</statusmessage>
                                  <messageid>223639802</messageid>
                                  <originator>88434</originator>
                                  <recipient>923336458112</recipient>
                                  <messagetype>SMS:TEXT</messagetype>
                                  <messagedata>testing by JAved for DLS</messagedata>
                                </acceptreport>
                                <acceptreport>
                                  <statuscode>0</statuscode>
                                  <statusmessage>Message accepted for delivery</statusmessage>
                                  <messageid>223639803</messageid>
                                  <originator>88434</originator>
                                  <recipient>923497105188</recipient>
                                  <messagetype>SMS:TEXT</messagetype>
                                  <messagedata>testing by JAved for DLS</messagedata>
                                </acceptreport>
                                </data>
                                </response>';




$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo $xml->data->acceptreport->messageid;
```

I also noticed you had a  "response"  closing tag missing from your xml so that might have been the problem you were having. I have added it in this example.